# How to Restore an Element Removed with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

if an element is removed using

```
$('.notification').remove();
```

How do we create it back.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't get *that particular instance* back. Using `$.remove()` removes it from the DOM. You can create a clone of it, move it around the DOM, hide it, etc., though. Depending on what your project requires, you likely have many other options.

If you're not too interested in that particular instance, you can create a new one. Suppose that was a div with a statement:

```
$("<div />").addClass("notification").text("I exist!").appendTo("body");
```

If you want to keep a copy of that particular element around, you can `$.clone()` it and remove the original:

```
var clone = $(".notification").clone(); // making zeh' clones!
$(".notification").remove();            // original is gone
$("body").append(clone);                // appears to have returned
```

Comment: Hi Jonathan,What u mean to say is that i can use `$.remove()` along with `$("<div />").addClass("notification").text("I exist!").appendTo("body");` this statemnet right?

Comment: @Hulk: I was saying you can remove the elements, and create new ones later. Yes.

Answer (score 11):

Check out the jQuery 1.4 method [`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/). It lets you "remove" elements from the DOM and saves them so they can be reinserted later.

Answer (score 6):

[detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) does what [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) does, with the difference that remove will also take out any event handlers on the element. So long as a reference is made at some point, an element can be removed or detached equally, and be returned to the DOM

```
noti = $('.notification').remove();
$('body').append( noti ); // later
```

Answer (score 0):

Even easier is to instead use .replaceWith() which returns what is replaced.
Put nothing as what it is replacing.

```
var backUpReplaced = $('.notification').replaceWith('');
```

Now your element is stored in a var but it's not in your page