# ng-include fails to include the template for second time after deleting the template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.templateDOM = templatePath;

<div id="Template" ng-include="templateDOM"></div>
```

**Scenario**

1. I have added the templatePath appended to scope.
2. After adding the templatePath Able to see the templateDOM in the page.
3. Now Removing the templateDOM from the page`jQuery("#templateDOM").remove();`.
4. Again I am trying executing  `$scope.templateDOM = templatePath;` this logic.
5. After executing 4th step I am not able to see the templateDOM in the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a query string (it could be timestamp from `Date.now()` ) behind of your template path like as :

```
$scope.templateDOM = '/tempalte/view.html?a=' + Date.now();

<div id="Template" ng-include="templateDOM"></div>
```

When query string change it will re-compile. Just, you should set path `with Date.now()` when you want re-compile it.

Another thing, I think it is not a good approach to delete element with jQuery. Instead of, you can use ng-if to remove it from DOM.

Comment: Great, it's working fine for me now after appending data.now(). and it's recompiling also thanks a lot...

Comment: @manjunathdr It is good. You'r well come . If you Choose my answer is correct it will made me glad :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use '' if you are directly accessing the template.

```
<div id="Template" ng-include="'templateDOM'"></div>
```

And your removal of template should be with the correct ID

```
jQuery("#template").remove();
```

I will suggest you to use ng-if for your div instead of removal with jquery

```
$scope.templateDOM = templatePath;

<div id="Template" ng-if="var" ng-include="templateDOM"></div>
```

Trigger `$scope.var` as true or false to show/hide the div in your template.

The problem was after removal of div , you are not adding back that div in your template. So triggering the $scope value for your ng-include won't make a difference because that div doesn't exist in your template anymore. So you have to add it back.
If you want to use Jquery, then follow this **scenario**:

1. Add the templatePath and append to scope.
2. After adding the templatePath Able to see the templateDOM in the
   page.
3. Now **Detach** the templateDOM from the
   page jQuery("#templateDOM").detach();.
4. Before executing  $scope.templateDOM = templatePath; ,**Append** the div back to the body of the document.

How to detach and then append the element back in jquery:[How to Restore an Element Removed with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301431/how-to-restore-an-element-removed-with-jquery)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It is not working because  can't get that particular instance of div back once you remove it using jquery

Comment: Actually i want to recompile the controller again after adding dom to the page, i dont want to play with the hide and show so

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.templateDOM = 'templatePath';

<div id="Template" ng-include="templateDOM"></div>
```

Comment: It wont work @hirarthi panchal?  it will appen the templatePath string to dom

Comment: tempalatepath  = it's path of the dom template

Answer (score 0):

In 4th step you are trying to include a div which is already removed?Can you try .detach() or .empty() instead of .remove?

Comment: i tried using detach and empty still template dom is not appending to page

Comment: Hey Instead of using jquery, try this ng-click="remove()" where remove function will empty the html. $scope.remove = function() {
    element.html('');
};

Comment: Still the same issue not able to append templateDom to page again after removing

Comment: Better,create a new DOM element with same ID after removing using angular.May I know why you are trying this?

Comment: Thanks a lot and it's resolved by 

Kamuran Sönecek comments

Answer (score 0):

- Actually Why you are using Jquery within angularjs? it's very bad. You can do it by `angular.element()`. **Because your code may be removed the DOM the current from scope**
- Then why you want to delete that template then add?

> You can do it by using `ng-show` or `ng-hide` or `ng-if`, like

---

```
<div id="Template" ng-show="isTemplate" ng-include="templateDOM"></div>
```

1. You need append the templatePath and use a flag like `$scope.isTemplate=true`
2. After adding the templatePath Able to see the templateDOM in the page.
3. Now hiding the templateDOM by using `$scope.isTemplate=false`
4. Again if you want to show that, then use `$scope.isTemplate=true`
5. After executing 4th step you can see that elemtn

Comment: Thanks a lot a for ur response it's resolve by 

Kamuran Sönecek comments