# I removed a div and I want to add it back

Tags: javascript

I removed a div using `$(".className").remove()` and I want to add it back

I tried the obvious, `$(".className").add()` but it doesn't get the job done. Any solutions?

Comment: Yes, you should have cloned it in a variable before removing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Restore an Element Removed with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301431/how-to-restore-an-element-removed-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to put it back, then you have to store it somewhere. If you just remove it, then you are throwing it away.

```
let $savedClassName = $(".className");
$savedClassName.remove();
```

Then to put it back you need to say where you want to put it. e.g.

```
$("#parent").append($savedClassName);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `remove` a block of `html`, its permanently gone. 
If you save that `div` before removing, then you can simply add it back. But If didn't save it and you want to get it back, you need to add it as string

```
var your_div = '<div class="my-div"><p>Hello World</p></div>';
$(parentDiv).append(your_div);
```

Comment: Bien vu. Well seen. Good point. +1